# userform inside the subfunction

Tags: excel, vba

I have created the following userform in workbook .

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJcfO.jpg]

This is my code

```
Sub Macro6()

Dim lines As Long
Dim letter As String
Dim no As String
Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim xRow As Long
Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$
Dim DataBook As Workbook, OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet

    count = Sheets.count

    If count > 1 Then
    For i = 1 To Sheets.count
    If Sheets(i).Name <> "Sheet1" And Sheets(i).Name <> "Execute" And Sheets(i).Name <> "DBCONNECTORS" And Sheets(i).Name <> "Cil Connectors" Then
        Sheets(i).Select
Set OutBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(i)
Dim myValue, myValue1, myValue2, myValue3, myValue4, Myvalue5, myValue6, myValue7, myValue8, myValue9, myValue10, myValue11 As Variant
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = OutSheet.Name
UserForm1.Show
Windows("DB.xlsm").Activate
Rows("1:1").Select
```

I am calling `UserForm1.Show` inside sub function after entering the details in `UserForm`.
Question: is it possible to **execute nextline in sub function** once I have issued the `UserForm1.Show`? If so, how?

Comment: if the userform is not modal, then it should run automatically. and if it is modal, all code will be at halt till the form is closed again (except code which is executed via the form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have issued the command `UserForm1.Show` in the sub, the sub stops running and the code on the form (initialize, show, waiting for user input on the form, etc.) will run.

This does not mean that the rest of the is neglected or just dropped. The remainder of the code merely got put on hold. Once the form is closed the rest of the code in your sub should run. Yet, at the point that you initiate the `UserForm` the focus shifts away from your sub and the `Form` with all its code and events gets "slid in between".

If you want the sheet to get activated (and the first row selected) before the `form` is shown then you should move the line `UserForm1.Show` to the end of the sub and run the lines `Windows("DB.xlsm").Activate` and `Rows("1:1").Select` before.

If you want this to happen once the form is shown then you'll have to either:

1. make the `form` [modeless](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251540.aspx) or
2. you'll have to shift the rest of your code into a place that gets run once the form is shown (for example UserForm_Initialize).

So, the code for the above two alternatives are:

Alternative 1

```
'... only copied over the last few rows or your above sub
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = OutSheet.Name
UserForm1.Show (False)
Windows("DB.xlsm").Activate
Rows("1:1").Select
```

Alternative 2

```
'... in the code module of the UserForm us the following
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Windows("DB.xlsm").Activate
Rows("1:1").Select
End Sub
```

Notes:

- The `modal` functionality does not only ensures that the rest of your code runs. Also - and perhaps most importantly - this allows a user to interact with the sheet and the form simultaneously. The form no longer has the exclusive focus. Read the above referenced link and make sure that this is what you want.
- Moving the rest of the code from your sub to `UserForm_Inizialize` is just a proposition. There are other places you could put the code such as `UserForm_Activate` or you could even decide for the rest to happen as the first even occurs on the `UserForm`.